# php uploading a csv file into a mysql table

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script where a user can upload a csv file into a table.  I got the tutorial from [shotdev.com](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-csv/php-upload-and-convert-import-csv-to-mysql/), I'm getting the following errors, what am I doing wrong?

****The following command is not allowed: copy**

**The following command is not allowed: fopen****

Page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
      <input name="fileCSV" type="file" id="fileCSV">
      <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Page2.php

```
<?
    copy($_FILES["fileCSV"]["tmp_name"],"shotdev/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"]); // Copy/Upload CSV

include 'datalogin.php';

    $objCSV = fopen("shotdev/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"], "r");
    while (($objArr = fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO customer ";
        $strSQL .="(CustomerID,Name,Email,CountryCode,Budget,Used) ";
        $strSQL .="VALUES ";
        $strSQL .="('".$objArr[0]."','".$objArr[1]."','".$objArr[2]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",'".$objArr[3]."','".$objArr[4]."','".$objArr[5]."') ";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    }
    fclose($objCSV);

    echo "Import completed.";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation imposed by the hosting provider (they seem to have put `fopen()` and `copy()` on the list of disabled functions, which is rather silly), in which case you probably can't do anything about it except ask the provider to relax the restriction.

Generally though, you're not handling the uploaded files properly using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file). Use it as shown in the example in the manual link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running PHP in safe mode or with certain functions disabled. For security reasons web hosts often disable file commands.

You could discuss your requirements with your web host - some are flexible enough to enable the functions for you if you ask nicely.

Otherwise you'll have to achieve it without using the disabled file commands. One way would be to create a `textarea` in an HTML form in which you paste the CSV. SUbmit it to your PHP script which then runs the MySQL import.

Hope that helps

Comment: btw, it's propably the setting *disable_functions* (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)